# Duplicate values contained in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to duplicate some values contained in a given colum by the value contained in another column of a dataframe.
For example, this is my dataframe:

```
Year <- rep(c('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'), 3)
LT <- rep(c(8, 9, 10), each=6)
Nind <- rep(c(10, 7, 5), each=6)
df <- data.frame(Year, LT, Nind)
```

what I would like to do is to replicate each LT for the respective value in LT by year, like this:

```
lt <- c(rep(8, 60), rep(9, 42), rep(10, 30))
yr <- c(rep(c('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'), each=10), 
rep(c('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'), each=7),rep(c('2011', 
'2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'), each=5))
df2 <- data.frame(yr, lt)
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Silvia

Comment: Please add the "desired result" to your question.

Comment: My desired result should be a data frame with two columns: Year and LT, in which LT is repeted the values included in Nind.
    lt <- c(rep(8, 60), rep(9, 42), rep(10, 30))
    yr <- c(rep(c('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'), each=10), rep(c('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'), each=7), rep(c('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'), each=5))
   df2 <- data.frame(yr, lt)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
df %>% setDT %>% .[,rep(rbind(Nind),Nind),by=c("Year","LT")] %>% .[,-3]
```

#### Result:

```
     Year LT
  1: 2011  8
  2: 2011  8
  3: 2011  8
  4: 2011  8
  5: 2011  8
 ---        
128: 2016 10
129: 2016 10
130: 2016 10
131: 2016 10
132: 2016 10
```

Comment: You know that you can just do `setDT(df)[,rep(rbind(Nind),Nind),by=c("Year","LT")][,-3]`, right? In other words, pipes just add unnecessary syntax in this case

Comment: And btw, you can just do `setDT(df)[rep(1:.N, Nind), -3]`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your suggestions, now it works.

Comment: @user3032235 If my question helped you and it "answered" the question you should check it as "answer". The arrow next to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using `expandRows()` from the `splitstackshape` package.

```
library('splitstackshape')    
df <- df %>% 
  expandRows(count = 'LT', drop = FALSE) %>% 
  select(-Nind)
```